# Bug highlighting random characters on VScode Terminal?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal, highlight

I suddenly got what appears to be some random highlights on my terminal in VScode. Whatever I try to write it just gets hidden by the yellow boxes you see in the screenshot. It even keeps the highlights in place even if I delete the characters. Has anyone experienced something similar?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using some sort of custom theme.  What if you change themes?

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: @TimothyG. I just found out that turning off Terminal > Integrated: GPU Acceleration in my settings eliminates the problem. I'm using the latest vscode 1.70.2 on a 12years old MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.13.6 and vscode might be starting to get a bit buggy with this setup.

Comment: Good find. You should post that as an answer. I think the gpu acceleration has caused similar graphical glitches in the past too.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that turning off Terminal > Integrated: GPU Acceleration in my settings eliminates the problem. I'm using the latest vscode 1.70.2 on a 12years old MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.13.6 and vscode might be starting to get a bit glitchy with this setup.